# Dependency injection php

Tags: object, dependency-injection, type-hinting

I have built a simple dependency injection container that I pass around my classes that need it, everything works and all is good.

My question is that say I have 2 classes such as

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {

    }
}

class B {
    public function __construct(A $a) {

    }
}
```

Should I enforce the typehinting in the class itself or in the injection container such as;

```
$di->set('A', function() {
     return new A();
});

$di->set('B', function(A $a) {
     return new B($a);
});
```

Should I do both or either/or.

For answers why is it better to use one over the other etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the first case, enforce the type hinting in the class itself.

This will make it clear for readers of the code what are the actual dependencies of the class.

If you decide to change the DI container (or hypothetically remove it) or reuse the classes in other project, it is good to have the type hinting in the class itself.

The DI container is there simply to help you manage dependencies.